# Скрипт вывода данных из массива

Tags: php

```
$cars = [
    ['name' => 'Такси 1', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
    ['name' => 'Такси 2', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
    ['name' => 'Такси 3', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
    ['name' => 'Такси 4', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
    ['name' => 'Такси 5', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
];
```

name - название машины, position - ее положение, isFree - признак свободна или занята.

Должен определить самое ближайшее и свободное такси до пассажира, который хочет куда-то поехать.

Положение пассажира также случайная величина, он может стоять в любой точке:
$passenger = rand(0, 1000);

Напишите скрипт, который для каждого такси будет выводить строку, вида:
<Название машины>, строит на <км, где стоит машина> км, до пассажира <км до пассажира> км (<занят/свободен>)</ - едет это такси>

Например:
"Такси 1, стоит на 15 км, до пассажира 3 км (занят)"
"Такси 2, стоит на 0 км, до пассажира 12 км (свободен) - едет это такси"
"Такси 3, стоит на 300 км, до пассажира 288 км (свободен)"

**Нельзя создавать свои функции

Данные и структуру массива менять запрещено.**

> Трудность вызвало "Должен определить самое ближайшее и свободное такси до пассажира, который хочет куда-то поехать."
> Ниже код который у меня получился:

```
    foreach ($cars as $k => $car) {
        echo $car['name'].", стоит на ".$car['position']." км, до пассажира ".(abs ($car['position'] - $passenger))." км ";
        if ($car['isFree'] == true) {
            echo "(свободен)";
        if ($car['name'] == $cars[$k]['name'] && $car['isFree'] == true) {
            echo " - едет это такси";
        }
        }
        else {
            echo "(занят)";
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Но оно не определяет ближайшее и свободное такси. Либо все разом пишет, либо через раз срабатывает(Я пробовал разные вариации, не понимаю как сделать без функции).

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: @Pashok Отредактировал.

Comment: Кому написать что бы закрыли тему? Но без пометки "обучающий материал"? Я уже указывал в чем проблема была и в принципе уже решил вопрос.

Comment: _Кому написать что бы закрыли тему_, вопрос уже закрыт, а вы правкой пытаетесь его переооткрыть. Зачем?

Comment: Нет. нужно ещё 11 символов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все заработало когда я написал вот так:

```
foreach($cars as $car) {
    $position = abs($car['position'] - $passenger);
    if ($car['isFree'] && (!isset($minPosition) || $position < $minPosition)) {
        $minPosition = $position;
        $name = $car['name'];
    }
}

foreach($cars as $car) {
    echo $car['name'] . " стоит на " . $car['position'] . " км, до пассажира " . abs($car['position'] - $passenger)." км (" . ($car['isFree'] ? "свободен" : "занят") . ")" . ($car['name'] == $name ? " - едет это такси" : "") . "<br>";
}
```